# Accessing the first object in an array of objects using handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am passing snapshot(from the database, it's an array of object) to another variable snapshot, which is used in the handlebar template. I am able to loop through snapshot using `{{each snaphot}}  {{/each}}`. How do I access the first element using handlebar?

```
app.get("/",function(req, res){
        res.render("home", {snapshot: snapshot});
    });


        //snapshot looks like this
    {
        {title:"abc",name:"sdc"},
        {title:"nbv",name:"kjh"},
        {title:"scd",name:"lok"}
    }
```

Comment: snapshot[0] ???

Comment: `snapshot looks like this` - no it doesn't, because that's not valid ... unless the outer `{}` were meant to be `[]`

Comment: but {{#each snapshot}} {{/each}} works for me. Which means handlebar is looping through snapshot. I tried snapshot.0.title, snapshot.[0].title but is not giving the expected result.